# Existing Redmine Project from Linux to Windows: Redmine is not migrated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

This is the error I encounter during rake.

> The Easy Project cannot start because the Redmine is not migrated!
>
> Please run `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` and than
>   `bundle exec rake easyproject:install RAILS_ENV=production` rake
>   aborted!

I try to run the command stated and it doesn't work. 
Do I need to install something? Because the `bundle install` is successful.

I thought running the `bundle install` after giving me the project will do.
The first developer used Linux, but im on Windows.

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving when you run that above command?

Comment: Where did you get those software...? Ask Easy Project team who took Redmine and modified it......

Comment: Already resolved. I used these ffg commands:  
  `bundle exec rake generate_secret_token`  
  `set RAILS_ENV=production`  
  `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already resolved. I used these ffg commands:

`bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
set RAILS_ENV=production 
bundle exec rake db:migrate`